# Cloudkit query about time and markers

Tags: objective-c, database, cloudkit

I Would like to make a request at the database apple cloudkit to Show markers on the map according Hours Openings and closing of a store for example. HERE'S WHAT I Tried to do But the displays nothing :

```
NSString * const date1 = @"open_hours";
NSString * const date2 = @"close_hours";

-(void)LoadStoresForLocation:(CLLocation*)userLocation completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *results))completionHandler{

NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];

 NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentTime BETWEEN date1 AND date2"];


CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc]initWithRecordType:StoreTable predicate:pred];

CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code create the operation but never runs it. You need a line such as:

```
[myCloudKitDatabase addOperation:queryOperation];
```

You also need to setup the various handler blocks for the operation. Read the docs for `CKQueryOperation`.

I also highly recommend you read the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987) in Apple's docs.